# Difficulty reading a matrix as a node in rdflib

Tags: matrix, rdflib

I created an RDF file where images are stored in nodes as matrices.
However when I try to read them I cannot get the matrix form:
For example

```
from rflib import Literal 
mm = np.random.normal(0,1,(3,3))
L = Literal(mm)
```

it is very easy to get the matrix back
with L.value

```
In [494]: L
Out[494]: rdflib.term.Literal(u'[[-1.39304728  0.39093531 0.88042378]\n   [ 0.22605682  0.56064787 -0.75176713]\n [ 0.57021203  0.31796492 -0.53303191]]')

 In [495]: L.value
 Out[495]: 
 array([[-1.39304728,  0.39093531,  0.88042378],
   [ 0.22605682,  0.56064787, -0.75176713],
   [ 0.57021203,  0.31796492, -0.53303191]])
```

However when I execute a SPARQL stored in image_nodes I get:

```
In [501]: res = [q for q in image_nodes]

In [502]: res[0][0]
Out[502]: rdflib.term.Literal(u'[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n ..., \n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]')

In [503]: (res[0][0]).value
Out[503]: u'[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n ..., \n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]\n [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]'
```

Why cant I get the matrix format this time? This is in unicode and very resistant to any transformation.
Thanks

Comment: could you provide a minimal example with the SPARQL query? at the moment it looks as if `res[0][0]` just consists of 0 values. It seems unlikely that rdflib or the sparql engine invented the literal though.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide the SPARQL query parts of this answer are guess-work...

If you create an `rdflib.Literal(obj)` RDFLib will try to convert the given object into a suitable RDF (XSD) representation. Certain python standard types are mapped [here](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/rdflib/term.py#L1415). If the given object doesn't have any of those types (like a `np.array`) the [`_castPythonToLiteral(obj)`](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/rdflib/term.py#L1399) method will fall back to just return `obj`. So the `L.value` that you observe here is the untouched `obj` that you passed into `Literal(obj)`, as can be seen in the [constructor code](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/master/rdflib/term.py#L577), which arguably is confusing. As the actual returned `inst` of the `Literal` also is a `unicode` object, you can get the "content" of the `Literal` with `unicode(L)`. This is important as it's also what will be stored in your stores / SPARQL endpoint.

Now if you retrieve your literal from a SPARQL endpoint and if `obj` was none of the standard types, then that endpoint only ever knew the string representation of `obj`, so it returns a `l = Literal(str_rep_of_obj)`. So from the SPARQL endpoint's standpoint that is just a string. RDFLib also only will see a string and that is why you now suddenly get a unicode string in `res[0][0].value`.

In order to fix this what you need to do is de-serialize the string content of `res[0][0]` into your `np.array`, e.g. with json like this:

```
l = Literal(json.dumps(mm.tolist()))
```

and then later

```
imagenode = np.array(json.loads(unicode(res_literal)))
```

One additional remark though... similarly to databases saving binary blobs such as images in the database itself is usually not a good idea. It's usually better to put that binary data somewhere and then save a link in the database. Isn't it cool that RDF uses URIs ;)